# Integrate NASM to a compiler written in C

Tags: c, linux, compiler-construction, pipe, nasm

I have a C program that generates nasm assembly. How can I assemble it with *nasm* and then link it with *ld* to generate the final executable?

The easiest thing would be to just pipe the compiler's output into nasm, but I wanted the process to be simple for the user: just type `compiler myfile` and get an executable. Even if I would go through that easy route, nasm does not seem to accept files from stdin; you have to specify them as arguments.

So what I have so far is: output the assembly to stdout, create a pipe between the main process' stdout and a child process' stdin, and this process would be a call to `nasm /dev/stdin`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you post the assembly and c code and how you're assembling/compiling?

Comment: There was a nasm feature request (https://sourceforge.net/p/nasm/feature-requests/31/) to treat filename `-` as stdin, but I don't think it got accepted.

Comment: The solution above is something I have been thinking about, I don't know if it works, but above all, is that the proper way to do such thing?

Comment: I think I formulated the question badly, but my main question is not "does it work", but "what is the best way of doing this". I have been searching this for weeks but it is very difficult to find anything about such specific question. One thing I could do is to look at GCC's code, but perhaps someone here already knows how this works.

Comment: Write the output to a temp file. Feed it to nasm as input. Delete the temp file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, your suggested procedure will not work, because `nasm` reads its input file twice (unless you suppress the preprocessor pass with the -a flag).

So it would be necessary that `/dev/stdin` be an ordinary file, not a pipe. And if it were going to be an ordinary file, it might as well have a name.

So just write your output to a temporary file, call nasm on that file, and then delete it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but a suggestion of how to implement such a helper script:

```
#!/bin/sh
SrcDir="$(mktemp -d)" || exit 1
trap "rm -rf '$SrcDir'" EXIT

cat > "$SrcDir/source.asm"
nasm "$@" "$SrcDir/source.asm"
```

The `mktemp -d` creates a new temporary directory.  The `trap` removes that directory and all its contents, when the shell exits.  Note that because the command is in doublequotes, the path to the directory is evaluated when the trap is set.  If one were to change `SrcDir` later, it would not affect the trap at all; the original temporary directory gets used and deleted.

Any parameters to the script will be passed to nasm as-is (due to `"$@"`), with the path to the temporary file as the final parameter.

This pattern is useful in all kinds of situations, because the temporary directory will get removed even if the script is aborted (due to say <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or because of a bug in the script).